# Pages with embedded views - a good aproximation?

Tags: views

I have a view with a listing of nodes. I want to create a page which contains the view as a block and lots of others features. I have followed this approach, but it seems to me that it is a little clumsy and there are better ones:

1) I have created a new type of content, with no fields.
2) I have created a new node of that content.
3) In the template.tpl.php I have made a suggestion for that type of content, to load a specific page--type-of-content.tpl.php page.
4) In that page I embed (php) my view and all the other features.

Is there a more straighforward method? This one works, but it seems rather convoluted.

Maybe creating the view as Page and altering the page? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You better use [Panles Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) to display everything in a single page and It allows you create complex layouts

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized
>   layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content
>   manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content
>   within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to
>   create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even
>   override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you
>   can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained
>   permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried Panels, and it is very easy to embed the View. However, my site is multilanguage, multidomain, and I need to pass Arguments (subdomain in which the user is, Nid of the content, etc.). These arguments are hard-coded in PHP, so cannot see where to include it in the Panel. I will keep playing around with Panels anyway.